# How to wire up a project upgraded from TypeScript 0.8.0.0 to 0.8.1.1

Tags: typescript

I'm revisiting an older project after having upgraded TypeScript from 0.8.0.0 to 0.8.1.1.

Visual Studio lists this error:

The command "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\0.8.0.0\tsc" "...\tsFile1.ts" "...\tsFile2.ts" exited with code 3

However, the path ...\0.8.0.0... to the tsc file doesn't exist on my system now.  Instead its 0.8.1.1.  Where is this path info stored?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit your project file; find the **BeforeBuild** entry then correct the path there.

For e.g.

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
 <Exec Command="&quot;$(PROGRAMFILES)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\0.8.0.0\tsc&quot;  @(TypeScriptCompile ->'&quot;%(fullpath)&quot;', ' ')" />
</Target>
```

Change that to

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
 <Exec Command="&quot;$(PROGRAMFILES)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\0.8.1.1\tsc&quot;  @(TypeScriptCompile ->'&quot;%(fullpath)&quot;', ' ')" />
</Target>
```